# Jest's setupFilesAfterEnv setupFile doesn't get read by VSCode IDE unless it's actually open

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, jest-dom

I've created a minimal repo where this issue is reproduced. If you have time, try it out: https://github.com/Danielvandervelden/jest-error-minimal-repro

**I have not tried any other editor than VSCode**

---

I'm struggling to get this to work. I'll get directly to the point. Here's my jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageReporters: ["lcov"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["/cypress", ".yalc"],
  preset: "ts-jest",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setupTests.ts"],
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
  testResultsProcessor: "jest-sonar-reporter",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": [
      "ts-jest",
      {
        tsconfig: "tsconfig.jest.json",
        diagnostics: false
      }
    ],
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
  },
  watchPlugins: ["jest-watch-typeahead/filename", "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"]
};
```

The most important one is the `setupFilesAfterEnv`, as you can see it points to `setupTests.ts` which indeed lives in the root directory of my project and looks like this:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
  useTranslation: () => ({ t: (key: string) => key }),
  Trans: (stringToTranslate: string) => stringToTranslate,
  initReactI18next: {
    type: "3rdParty",
    init: jest.fn()
  }
}));
```

Extremely simple and concise. The most important line is the `import` statement for `@testing-library/jest-dom` since this enables `expect().toBeInTheDocument()`, which we use in many different test files.

I'm using a config where I have a separate `tsconfig.json` for `*.test.tsx?` files and normal `*.tsx?` files. Here's the `tsconfig.jest.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }],
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["dom", "ESNext"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.test.ts", "src/**/*.test.tsx", "setupTests.ts"]
}
```

And just for information's sake, here's the regular `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }],
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["dom", "ESNext"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "types": ["node", "./types.d.ts"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.test.ts", "src/**/*.test.tsx"]
}
```

Now the issue is as follows, I have a very simple test:

```
describe("component", () => {
 it("should render children if no error is thrown", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(
      <MicrofrontendErrorBoundary>
        <ThrowComponent />
      </MicrofrontendErrorBoundary>
    );

    expect(getByText("An error occurred!")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Whenever my `setupTests.ts` is open, and my IDE can see that we `import` the `@testing-library/jest-dom` package inside of it we have no problem. `toBeInTheDocument()` is defined perfectly fine. However, when we **close** this file, all of a sudden all of the `toBeInTheDocument()` function calls get red underlines and errors out with the following error:

`Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<HTMLElement>'.ts(2339)`

Then when I open the `setupTests.ts` file back up, it works flawlessly and it can recognize the types! Obviously this error will go away if I just `import` the `@testing-library/jest-dom` inside of every single test file that uses `.toBeInTheDocument()` but this defeats the whole purpose of having a `setupTests.ts` file.

Tests are passing just fine, this is purely IDE related.

The even weirder thing is **sometimes** when I `reload window` in VSCode without having `setupTests.ts` open, it works. But then out of nowhere, it stops working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look in you repo and got that ts error as well.
Try to modify **tsconfig.json** a little bit:

```json
  ...
  "types": ["node", "./types.d.ts", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
  ...
```

UPD:
Forgot to mentioned that I also deleted that line from **tsconfig.json**:

```
"exclude": ["src/**/*.test.ts", "src/**/*.test.tsx"]
```

UPD:
Both configs tsconfig.json and tsconfig.jest.json work correctly (npm test and tsc commands work correctly, both of them use own configs). The issue that IDE use only tsconfig.json for internal TS compilator and it renders errors in *.test.ts/tsx files.

There is just a proposal how use multi tsconfig.ts files based on folder structures - https://github.com/smlkA/jest-error-minimal-repro

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried doing all sorts of configurations inside `tsconfig.json`. None of them worked. Same issue in the reproduction repository, this does not fix the issue.

Comment: Hmm, interesting as it fixed for me (P.S. I have cloned your repo and tested in it)

Comment: I see you've done this inside of the default `tsconfig.json` and not inside the `tsconfig.jest.json`. This is indeed a fix, but the reason why we have different configs is that both `cypress` and `jest` add `expect()` functions. And if we do them all through the same `tsconfig.json`, we get clashing definitions... It seems like there's no way to make separate configs work?

Comment: npm test works correctly and it means all ok with tsconfig.jest.json. I think the reason is that TS compiler inside IDE may use only tsconfig.json and that causes error in IDE. But actual npm test works well.

Comment: P.S. with your original configs I have errors with describe and it functions in my IDE but still npm test and tsc work ok (as both that commands know how to use own configs )

Comment: about cypress. In one project we had a separate cypress folder with own tsconfig.json. In that case that cypress folder was excluded from the root tsconfig.json and it did not cause any IDE error (at least in vs code).